# asp:Repeater bind only if a property is true

Tags: asp.net, repeater, nested-repeater

is it possible to put a repeater inside a if statement like

```
<% if(1 == 2) { %>                                                           
 Return: <asp:Repeater runat="server" DataSource='<%# Eval("returnDetails") %>'>
     <ItemTemplate>
       <%# Eval("from") %> 
       <%# Eval("to") %> 
     </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
<% } %>
```

But this runs even if `isReturnDetailsExist` is false, and so throws exception that `returnDetails` doesn't exist, anyone?

Comment: It is better to filter the data source in code behind.

Comment: can you put the code `isReturnDetailsExist` where you are receiving the value as well ?

Comment: Yes, it works that time,,as its true in that case - Ali
AVD- But this case wil again come even in that case when binding in repeater

Comment: I guess my question is from where do you get the value of `isReturnDetailsExist`, is this a property from your code behind ? the value of `isReturnDetailsExist` might be refreshed on page load, can you check the value on break point ?

Comment: Yes....even I removed isReturnDetailsExist and I put if (1 == 2), in that case too it runs

Comment: I edited the question to be more precise (1== 2)

Comment: I just run your code and it works fine at my end, could you take `DataSource='<%# Eval("returnDetails") %>` out of your code and try again ?

Comment: If I remove this it will work for sure, but this is what I needed, I can't remove that...this is what I am working on

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54959/discussion-between-ali-shahrokhi-and-luckyy).